# How do I install IBM Lotus Symphony after receiving the error in the description?

Tags: 12.10, 32-bit, alien, ibm-lotus-symphony

```
Warning: Skipping conversion of scripts in package symphony: postinst postrm preinst prerm
Warning: Use the --scripts parameter to include the scripts.
mkdir: cannot create directory `symphony-3.0.1': File exists
unable to mkdir symphony-3.0.1:  at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package.pm line 257.
```

Is the error I receive after running:

```
sudo alien -i '/home/brentonhorne/DownloadDirector/symphony-3.0.1.i586.rpm'
```

Where the rpm symphony file is located at the place detailed in the code above. (I couldn't find a deb file at the IBM Lotus Symphony site)

and I have run

```
sudo alien -c '/home/brentonhorne/DownloadDirector/symphony-3.0.1.i586.rpm'
```

Where `-c` equates to running `--scripts`.

I am running 32 bit 12.10 if these details are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the Ubuntu version, "symphony-fp2_3.0.1_i386.deb"

You may find it here:

[http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/preconfig.jsp?id=2010-10-19+16%3A31%3A30.217086R&S_TACT=&S_CMP=](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/preconfig.jsp?id=2010-10-19%2016:31:30.217086R&S_TACT=&S_CMP=)

Then you will also need to install "libnotify1", which you can find here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/libnotify1/download

Good luck!